# ADODB and ADO.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is it particularly bad practice to mix and match ADODB e.g. Connections etc and ADO.NET e.g. SQLConnections etc in the same application?  I am trying to incorporate some VB6 code into an ASP.NET application (VB.NET).

Comment: Do yourself a favor. Translate everything to ADO.NET and forget ADODB. Especially with an ASP.NET app

Comment: could i ask why, before I upvote your comment?